# grails create-app file not found

Tags: ubuntu, grails

Just trying to get started with grails on a fresh laptop. 
(Running ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

| Grails Version: 3.2.6

| Groovy Version: 2.4.7

| JVM Version: 1.8.0_121

The following code gives the following error:

```
connor@connor-Swift-SF314-51:~/GrailsTutorial$ grails create-app TaskList
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: /home/connor/GrailsTutorial/TaskList/gradle.properties (No such file or directory) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I've tried reinstalling and running through multiple tutorials, but so far, still no success.
Any ideas?

(Here's the full stacktrace if you want...)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/connor/GrailsTutorial/TaskList/gradle.properties (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileResource.getOutputStream(FileResource.java:259)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileResource.getOutputStream(FileResource.java:234)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils.getOutputStream(ResourceUtils.java:843)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils.copyWithFilterSets(ResourceUtils.java:680)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ResourceUtils.copyResource(ResourceUtils.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:559)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.doFileOperations(Copy.java:892)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.execute(Copy.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.copySrcToTarget(CreateAppCommand.groovy:616)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.copySkeleton(CreateAppCommand.groovy:585)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.handle(CreateAppCommand.groovy:251)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.handle(CreateAppCommand.groovy:332)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.executeCommandWithArgumentValidation(GrailsCli.groovy:286)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:262)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Try this: `mkdir ~/tmproj && cd ~/tmproj && grails create-app someapp`.

Comment: Does the `/home/connor/GrailsTutorial/TaskList` directory already exist?